# CognitoIdentityID is empty in Go lambda function with Cognito authentication and API Gateway

Tags: go, aws-lambda

I have an AWS lambda function written in Go behind an API Gateway. I'm using Cognito with App integration and OAuth Client credentials grant for authentication. I need to know which App client sent the request inside the lambda function, but all the fields related to Cognito (`CognitoIdentityID`, `CognitoIndetityPoolID`, `AccountID`, etc.) are empty in the context and the request. I can only see the Bearer Authorization in the header of the request. I'm printing the values as follows:

```
var forwardRequest = func(ctx context.Context, request events.APIGatewayProxyRequest) (events.APIGatewayProxyResponse, error) {
    println(fmt.Sprintf("Request arrived: Stage: %s, Method: %s, Path: %s",
        request.RequestContext.Stage, request.HTTPMethod, request.Path))
    lc, _ := lambdacontext.FromContext(ctx)
    println(fmt.Sprintf("lc: %+v", lc))
    println(fmt.Sprintf("request: %+v", request))
    ...
}

func main() {
    // Make the handler available for Remote Procedure Call by AWS Lambda
    lambda.Start(forwardRequest)
}
```

I'm already using **Lambda Proxy integration**, as answered in similar questions. I attach a screenshot of the [configuration of the API Gateway method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7eK7p.png). I can't enable "Invoke with caller credentials".

How can I know which client sent the request?.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer: Cognito's client ID is not in the `Cognito*` fields but in the `Authorizer` of the request:

```
func(ctx context.Context, request events.APIGatewayProxyRequest) (events.APIGatewayProxyResponse, error) {
    var clientID string
    if claimsMap, ok := request.RequestContext.Authorizer["claims"].(map[string]interface{}); ok {
        clientID, ok = claimsMap["client_id"].(string)
        ...
    }
    ...
```